# Dynamic Linq failing when using Contains against Int Field

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using Entity Frameworks 4.1.0.0 and MySQL.Data.Entity 6.5.4.0 and when I try and generate a dynamic query for a range of integers, I get an error of:

> No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32'

This seems to work fine when using a similar structure to check against Strings..but I want to expand this to support the other db fields I have in my data.

Code Example:

```
        int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 3, 4 };

        IQueryable<entityname> list = db.tablename.Where("Id.Contains(@0)", ids);
```

I have added in the Dynamic.cs to my project and followed along with
http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html
but there has been no difference then using the Dynamic I loaded via Nuget.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean `@0.Contains(Id)`?

Comment: Normally it would be something like that, but I'm just putting up some test code and specifying the column manually to produce/test out the error.

Comment: It is the @0.Contains(outerIt.Id). I've implemented the same from that blog. Only issue is that, while nuget will get updated, you'll have to download the source from git and reapply your changes each time there's an update

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is slightly different:

```
IQueryable<entityname> list = db.tablename.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.Id)", ids);
```

following the link you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if a given (variable) int value is contained within a entity column, you can do the following using Dynamic Linq:

```
return query.Where(String.Format("{0}.ToString().Contains(@0)", field), value);
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58151331/1233379) for an extension method that can perform such task with strings, integers and booleans column types in a rather seamless way.