# C# Linq Column Name as variable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table where I want to make a query on variable columns.
Like:

```
private void query(string column, string value) {

    using (var db = new myDB()) {

        var s1 = (from c in db.Components
                  where (**column** == **value**)
                  select new {c.id, **column**});
    }
}
```

lets say I want to look for a supplier then it would be like:

```
var s1 = (from c in db.Components
          where (c.supplier == "abc")
          select new {c.id, c.supplier});
```

is there a way to pass the column name as variable?

Comment: please see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148309/how-do-i-reference-a-field-in-linq-based-on-a-dynamic-fieldname)

Comment: and please do a proper search before posting a new question here at SO, because it hurts your repo

Comment: You can also use [Dynamic Query library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example can be useful i guess.

```
 void BindGridTypeSafe()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext northwind = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var query = from p in northwind.Products
                    where p.CategoryID == 3 && p.UnitPrice > 3
                    orderby p.SupplierID
                    select p;

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    void BindGridDynamic()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext northwind = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var query = northwind.Products
                             .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
                             .OrderBy("SupplierID");

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: thx for the example, i tried that out but it threw me an exception. I found out that since im using entityframework it's mandatory to write it.COLUMNNAME (it.supplier). that solved my problem with using dynamic linq. THX!

Comment: This is used by adding Linq.Dynamic namespace.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way is to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Something like:

```
var s1 = (from c in db.Components
    where(column + "=" + value)
    select new {c.id, **column**});
```

Comment: same example as above, user mentioned using entityframework andit's mandatory to write it.COLUMNNAME

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to add library System.Linq.Dynamic as a reference and do:

```
string columnName = "Supplier";
var s1 = Suppliers
    .Where(String.Format("{0} == \"abc\"", columnName))
    .Select(new {c.id, c.supplier};
```

Following is a complete working example of Dynamic Linq, where column-name is a parameter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lstContacts = new List<Contact>{
            new Contact{Id = 1, Active = true, Name = "Chris"}, 
            new Contact{Id = 2, Active = true, Name = "Scott"}, 
            new Contact{Id = 3, Active = true, Name = "Mark"}, 
            new Contact{Id = 4, Active = false, Name = "Alan"}};

        string columnName = "Active";
        List<Contact> results = lstContacts.Where(String.Format("{0} == true", columnName)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id.ToString() + " - " + item.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Active
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You can experiment with this [.net-fiddle-here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8tp7K3)

Answer (score 1):

I'm resurrecting this old thread because I had to work around that issue with ASP.NET Core 2.2 today. I used the [**System.Linq.Dynamic.Core**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) NuGet package to create the following extension method, which works beautifully if you need to check if multiple given string values are contained within multiple given columns.

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereContains<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    string field,
    string value,
    bool throwExceptionIfNoProperty = false,
    bool throwExceptionIfNoType = false)
    where TEntity : class
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(field);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.String:
                return query.Where(String.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", field), value);
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                var boolValue = (value != null
                    && (value == "1" || value.ToLower() == "true"))
                    ? true
                    : false;
                return query.Where(String.Format("{0} == @0", field), boolValue);
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                return query.Where(String.Format("{0}.ToString().Contains(@0)", field), value);

            // todo: DateTime, float, double, decimals, and other types.

            default:
                if (throwExceptionIfNoType)
                    throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("Type '{0}' not supported.", typeCode));
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (throwExceptionIfNoProperty)
            throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("Property '{0}' not found.", propertyInfo.Name));
    }
    return query;
}
```

The code can be used with .NETStandard/.NETCore (using the aforementioned [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) package) and also with ASP.NET 4.x (using the [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) package).

For further info regarding the WhereContains extension method and a full use-case info, check out [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-set-column-name-programmatically-dynamic-linq-where-iqueryable/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Just use typeof to use the column name

```html
public string columnName(string Id, string columnName, string columndata)
        {
            var story = _CidbContext.Stories.Where(m => m.Id.ToString() == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var property = typeof(Story).GetProperty(columnName);
            if (property != null)
            {

                var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(columndata, property.PropertyType);

                property.SetValue(story, convertedValue);
                _CidbContext.SaveChanges();
                return "Data Saved";
            }
            return "No Column found";
        }
```