# Dynamic Linq query Contains List

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, arraylist, contains

I am using dynamic Linq for generic search.
I have list of Ids:

```
List<int> idList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6};
```

In plain Linq, I would write:

```
q = q.Where(a => idList.Contains(a.MyId));
```

But now I have to use `System.Linq.Dynamic` because I don't know in advance name of the column.

```
string someId = "CustomId";
q = q.Where("@0"+ ".Contains(" + someId + ")", idList.ToArray());
```

But this gives error:

> "No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32'"

How can I achieve this?

Is there some extension library that implements `Contains` for `dynamic` Linq or some other way.

Comment: Use the expression tree.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651080/dyanmic-linq-failing-when-using-contains-against-int-field

Comment: The expression tree is solution as described in accepted answer below.
@pil0t question may be duplicate but the answer is not. There the only given solution required changes to the library, while here I got answer how to just extend it easily with Expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write something like this that builds your query function dynamically:

```
public static Func<ObjT, bool> PropertyCheck<ObjT, PropT>(string propertyName, Expression<Func<PropT, bool>> predicate)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjT));
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjT, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(predicate, propExpr), paramExpr).Compile();
}
```

Then, it could be used like this:

```
foos.Where(PropertyCheck<Foo, int>("MyId", x => idList.Contains(x)));
```

Of course, you could also just provide your own `Where` extension method that does all that at once:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T, PropT>(this IEnumerable<T> self, string propertyName, Expression<Func<PropT, bool>> predicate)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyName);
    return self.Where<T>(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(predicate, propExpr), paramExpr).Compile());
}
```

```
foos.Where<Foo, int>("MyId", x => idList.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `expressions` to do this dynamic query, try something like this, for sample:

import these namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
```

And try this:

```
// a reference parameter
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof (YourType), "x");

// contains method
var containsMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof (string)});

// reference a field
var fieldExpression = Expression.Property(instance, "PropertyName");

// your value
var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(yourId);

// call the contains from a property and apply the value
var containsValueExpression = Expression.Call(fieldExpression, containsMethod, valueExpression);

// create your final lambda Expression
var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<YourType, bool>>(containsValueExpression, x);

// apply on your query
q = q.Where(finalLambda);
```

*Obs: make sure your property has a method called `contains`.*

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of Dynamic LINQ then you can see that parsing in many cases depends on variable `predefinedTypes`.

In your case you need change this variable like this

```
static readonly Type[] predefinedTypes = {
    ....
    ,typeof(List<int>)
};
```

after that next code will be work

```
List<int> idList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6};
....
string someId = "CustomId";
q = q.Where("@0.Contains(" + someId + ")", idList);
```

Comment: Where would put these predefinedTypes.
Did you mean to override DynamicLinq.cs class or to extended these types somehow?

Comment: @Boris i mean edit this variable in `DynamicLinq.cs`

Comment: I have installed Linq.Dynamic via nuget and it is a library so I can't edit code.
I know I can download it's source from github and then change it but I would prefer not having to do that.

Comment: @Boris in some cases it may be useful :-)

Comment: that I agree.
+1 for usefulness.

Comment: Is there a way to create it in a string only way ? Something like                  q = q.Where("(new List<int>{ 1, 5, 6}).Contains(outerIt.CustomId));

Comment: @Franki1986, not sure, that DynamicLinq can parse all language construction, so possibly you can do this with a bit another syntax, or can't. But you can try :) I not watch to this library, so possibly even this workaround not needed

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, I tried it but this does not work, I mean is this possible with another syntax.. Theretically this is nothing but a static array..

Comment: @Franki1986, but to parse it, library can be more complicated, so seems,  workaround with parameter is one way, to pass constant list to query. But, as i say before, possibly something has changed now :)

Answer (score 1):

@Felipe Oriani in his 90% answer used the `string.Contains` method and the `yourId` single value, but asked was:

`q = q.Where(a => idList.Contains(a.MyId));`

which is member (property) access to the `a`.

So here is the final tested extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates lambda expression predicate: (TEntity entity) => collection.Contains(entity.property)
/// </summary>
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ContainsExpression<TEntity, TProperty, TCollection>(
    this TCollection collection, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property
)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TProperty>
{
    // contains method
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(TCollection).GetMethod(nameof(collection.Contains), new[] { typeof(TProperty) });

    // your value
    ConstantExpression collectionInstanceExpression = Expression.Constant(collection);

    // call the contains from a property and apply the value
    var containsValueExpression = Expression.Call(collectionInstanceExpression, containsMethod, property.Body);

    // create your final lambda Expression
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsValueExpression, property.Parameters[0]);

    return result;
}
```

The example:

```
List<int> idList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6 };

Expression<Func<MyEntity,int>> idExpression = entity => entity.Id;
var contains = idList.ContainsExpression(idExpression)

IQueryable<MyEntity> q = DbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Where(contains);
```

Comment: I like this solution more. But it has problem when I use string[] instead of List<string>, because it cant find the Contains method.  I fix the issue by changing to ```var containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<TProperty>).GetMethod(nameof(ICollection<TProperty>.Contains), new[] { typeof(TProperty) });```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin this cat would be to convert the contains to ORs.

someArray.Constains(someField) is equivalent to:

someField == someArray[0] or someField == someArray[1] and so on.

It's not ideal but if the array is small it could work.