# how to add IN clause inside where using dynamic linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have create `where clause` for `equal` successfully using `dynamic linq expression` using following code-

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause = null;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
            Expression filterExpression = null;
            List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>(){new Filter(){PropertyName= "id" , Value="2" , Operation = "Equal"}}
            var DistinctItems = filters.GroupBy(x => x.PropertyName).Select(y => y.First());
            foreach (var filterItem in DistinctItems)

            {
                var member = Expression.Property(parameter, filterItem.PropertyName);
                var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

                if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
                    throw new NotSupportedException();

                var propertyValue = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(filterItem.Value.ToString());
                var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
                var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType);
                Expression equality = null;
                switch (filterItem.Operation)
                {

                    case "Equal":
                        equality = Expression.Equal(member, valueExpression);
                        break;
                    case "LessThan":
                        equality = Expression.LessThan(member, valueExpression);
                        break;
                    //case "In": how to do for IN forexample where id in                
                    //(1,2)
                    //    equality = Expression.(member, valueExpression);
                    //    break;
                }


                if (filterExpression == null)
                {
                    filterExpression = equality;
                }
                else
                {
                    filterExpression = Expression.And(filterExpression, equality);

                }
            }

            if (filterExpression != null)
            {
                whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filterExpression, parameter);
            }

            return whereClause;
```

> How to do it for IN clause , for example - Where Id IN (1,2)

Comment: Take a look at this thread-[Linq to Entities - SQL “IN” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: I want to create left and right expression but want to use IN clause

Comment: What about this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971202/474702